# Constant template parameter class manages to link externally

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class foo with an enum template parameter and for some reason it links to two versions of the ctor in the cpp file.

```
enum Enum
{
    bar,
    baz
};

template <Enum version = bar>
class foo
{
public:
    foo();
};

// CPP File
#include "foo.hpp"

foo<bar>::foo() { cout << "bar"; }
foo<baz>::foo() { cout << "baz"; }
```

I'm using msvc 2008, is this the standard behavior?
Are only type template parameters cannot be linked to cpp files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specializing both forms of the contstructor.  Why are you surprised it links both forms in?

Comment: Maybe because one isn't referenced?

Comment: Because usually when I link to a template class it's members cannot be implemented in the cpp file.

Comment: @sbi:  Just because it isn't referenced doesn't mean it should be stripped.  The compiler "may" strip it but its by no means guaranteed.
@the_drow: You can implement members in a CPP file if you are specialising the template.

Comment: Behavior for that code is undefined. You need to declare the specialization in the header file. And you missed the `template<>` prefix.